# Can't install Blender GIS addon, Mac

Tags: python, add-on

- Blender 2.80
- Mac OSX 20.15.1
- Python 2.7.15

Trying to install [Blender GIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) using edit > prefferences > addons > install.

Addon installs:

```
Modules Installed (BlenderGIS-master) from '/Users/rider25/Desktop/BlenderGIS-master.zip' into '/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons'
```

but will not activate, returning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import geoscene
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/geoscene.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .operators.utils import mouseTo3d
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/operators/utils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bgis_utils import placeObj, adjust3Dview, showTextures, addTexture, getBBOX, DropToGround, mouseTo3d, isTopView
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/operators/utils/bgis_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ...core import BBOX
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .basemaps import GRIDS, SOURCES, MapService, GeoPackage, TileMatrix
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/core/basemaps/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .mapservice import MapService, TileMatrix, BBoxRequest, BBoxRequestMZ
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/core/basemaps/mapservice.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .gpkg import GeoPackage
  File "/Users/rider25/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/BlenderGIS-master/core/basemaps/gpkg.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/python/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/python/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Users/brecht/dev/build_darwin/deps/Release/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi. Seems like this has already been reported on the github, here: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/213 Issues with add-ons are generally best resolved by contacting the author directly, I think.

Comment: Solved with downloading latest Blender [link](https://builder.blender.org/download/) (as per the author's response to the issue linked by @RayMairlot

Comment: You mean: Mac OSX 10.15.1

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved by downloading the latest build (2.82-a) found at:
[builder.blender.org/download/](https://builder.blender.org/download/)